# How to build libtiff's tiffsplit as a portable commandline app for redistribution to PPC / Intel

Tags: macos, gcc

I need the tiffsplit utility from Libtiff (http://www.libtiff.org/) to include it as a commandline app with another piece of software.

I don't want the user to have to install the full libtiff library by make / sudo make install. So my question is how can I create a portable app of tiffsplit using gcc and static linking? All I need is a tiffsplit executable file without dependencies to anything external.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what I tried thus far is this - which seemed to work but needs further testing...

0) edit libtiff.h to disable `JPEG_SUPPORT`, `PIXARLOG_SUPPORT`, and `ZIP_SUPPORT`

1) configure libtiff for i386 and ppc:

`./configure  CFLAGS="-O -arch i386 -arch ppc" CXXFLAGS="-O -arch i386 -arch ppc"  LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch ppc" --disable-dependency-tracking`

2) `make`

3) go to where you built libtiff `/tools/.libs` folder by terminal and copy out tiffsplit

4) terminal: `otool -L tiffsplit` to list its dependencies

5) go to where you built libtiff `/libtiff/.libs` folder by terminal and copy out libtiff.5.dylib

6) put it in the same folder as the tiffsplit executable

7) terminal: `install_name_tool -change /usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib ./libtiff.5.dylib tiffsplit`